# Youtube-dl and Shell speed

Tags: ffmpeg, ubuntu-14.04, youtube-dl

So I've been experimenting with youtube-dl on Ubuntu 14 recently and I should say downloading is well fast even I have a 1GB Ubuntu LAMP but when it comes to triggering FFMPEG and deleting process hangs for a good time. Even worked with -k but as soon as FFMPEG process is completed, it takes time to respond. I do understand this is a big subject but I'd really like to hear your thoughts, what amazes me is how a website like [this](http://www.youtube-mp3.org/)is running in less than a second? Here is what I have,

```css
[youtube] UxxajLWwzqY: Downloading webpage
[youtube] UxxajLWwzqY: Downloading video info webpage
[youtube] UxxajLWwzqY: Extracting video information
[info] Writing video description metadata as JSON to: /var/www/html/download/Icona Pop - I Love It (feat. Charli XCX) [OFFICIAL VIDEO].info.json
[download] Destination: /var/www/html/download/Icona Pop - I Love It (feat. Charli XCX) [OFFICIAL VIDEO].m4a
[download] 100% of 2.73MiB in 00:00
[ffmpeg] Correcting container in "/var/www/html/download/title.m4a"
[ffmpeg] Destination: /var/www/html/download/title.mp3
Deleting original file /var/www/html/download/title.m4a (pass -k to keep)
```

```html
youtube-dl "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UxxajLWwzqY" --write-info-json  --extract-audio --audio-format mp3  -o "/var/www/html/download/%(title)s.%(ext)s"
```

I really don't understand how this is done so fast? Is there anything I'm missing?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am having the same issue, i was able to resolve it by running against a playlist instead.